# Pandas Check two data frame columns and access third value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very  beginner to pandas though I solved same case  with comparison
here is data frame I was working

```
s= [
     {
         'from':0,
         'to':400000000,
         'value':0.01
     },
     {
        'from':400000001,
        'to':500000000,
        'value':0.015
    },
    {
        'from':500000001,
        'to':1000000000,
        'value':0.03
    },
    {
        'from':1000000001,
        'to':10000000000,
        'value':0.04
    }
 ]
```

I want to compare two fields  i.e from and to and get third value that is value
suppose the car price range is between 0 and 400000000 then I may get commission of 1% i.e 0.01 bla bla
Any way of doing this in pandas way.
Here is little thing I worked on but I got empty data series

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s)

df = df[(df['from']<=0) &(400000000<df['to'])]['value']
print(df)
```

Comment: need `400000000<=df['to']` instead `400000000<df['to']` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think correct way is with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select column by mask, also is change `<=` from `<` for second condition:

```
s = df.loc[(df['from']<=0) & (df['to']<=400000000), 'value']
print(s)
0    0.01
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks both answers work fine can you let me know what is difference between above ans and your ans thanks for answer

Comment: @nava - because if use `df[df['from'].le(0) & df['to'].le(400000000)]` it select all rows and then select `value` column, if use `df.loc[(df['from']<=0) & (df['to']<=400000000), 'value']` both operation working togetehr, so faster.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to apply those conditions correctly. Since there is no value that satisfies both conditions. You can do:

```
df[df['from'].le(0) & df['to'].le(400000000)]['value']
```

And it will result in:

```
0    0.01
Name: value, dtype: float64
```